# .htaccess redirect to language subfolder

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, typo3, realurl

**What I have:**

- there are two languages installed: German and English
- language-versions are managed with subfolders (www.domain.com/de/ and www.domain.com/en/)
- machine: Typo3 4.5.4 / RealUrl installed
- mod_rewrite is enabled an works

**What I want to do:**

- redirect requests without language subfolder to the German version
- e.g. domain.com/any/test/folder/ to domain.com/**de**/any/test/folder

**What I tried:**

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/(?!(?:(?:de|en)/))(.*)$ /de/$1
```

**Occuring problems:**

- all requests were directed to domain.com/de/index.php
- it caused an error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)
- maybe it fails with Typo3's htaccess entries?

**my hole .htaccess-file:**

```
# Enable URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Change this path, if your TYPO3 installation is located in a subdirectory of the website root.
# RewriteBase /

# Rule for versioned static files, configured through:
# - $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['versionNumberInFilename']
# - $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['versionNumberInFilename']
# IMPORTANT: This rule has to be the very first RewriteCond in order to work!
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(php|js|css|png|jpg|gif|gzip)$ $1.$3 [L]

# Stop rewrite processing, if we are in the typo3/ directory.
RewriteRule ^(typo3/|t3lib/|fileadmin/|typo3conf/|typo3temp/|uploads/|favicon\.ico) - [L]

# Redirect http://example.com/typo3 to http://example.com/typo3/index_re.php and stop the rewrite processing.
RewriteRule ^typo3$ typo3/index_re.php [L]

#301 redirection for language mode
RedirectMatch permanent ^/(?!(?:(?:de|en)/))(.*)$ /de/$1

# If the file/symlink/directory does not exist => Redirect to index.php.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

# Main URL rewriting.
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

**So, what can I do?**

Comment: This is definitely related to regexes but Im not at home with rewrite rules to give direct advice. I tried http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/ but it dit not recognize your "RedirectMatch permanen" rule. As for the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS, could it be that the resulting url is offered again (and again) to be transformed?

Comment: You could also use the content negotiation `Accept-Language: de` header to help determine the initial redirect http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html or even geoip / geodns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(?!de/|en/)(.*) /de/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: + RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f this was my choice thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use something more simple, like this:

```
# if user didn't specify a valid language subfolder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|de)/
# redirect user to default language subfolder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /de/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I tried both solutions (Tom's and Qtax's), but they only work without negation! So something like RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(en|de)/ works perfectly! By adding negation the "too many redirects"-error occurs after redirecting to http://domain.com/hallo/hallo/hallo/hallo/hallo/hallo/hallo/hallo/hallo/hallo/hallo/hallo/hallo/hallo/hallo/hallo/hallo/hallo/hallo/hallo/hallo/path/i/entered/ Code: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|de)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /hallo/$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: because you cant go to admin panel:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|de|typo3)/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /de/$1 [L,R=301]

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to use htacces as you can configure this behaviour in your realUrl configuration. Just define this part in your config array:

```
    'preVars' => array(
      array(
        'GETvar' => 'L',
        'valueMap' => array(
            'de' => '0',
            'en' => '1',
            'fr' => '2',
            ),
        'valueDefault' => 'de',
        ),
),
```

This will give you a redirect to ../de/...

Comment: this is true but this kind of redirection is very low compared to htaccess I think