# Htaccess redirect if url contain language and file extension?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a large list with redirected url's and need a global rule for url's with languages. For example. All /fr/ .jsp files i need to redirect to /fr/ and all /es/ files with extension .jsp to /es, i tried so with help from other stackoverflow topics but this don't work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/es/*.jsp$
RewriteRule ^es/$ /es [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one rule would work for both requirements:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(es|fr)/.+?\.jsp$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(ru|de)/.+?\.jsp$ /en [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Can i add here also url redirect for language which don't exist on new website? For example Russian /ru/.jsp files to /en? I tried from here to solve problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064603/htaccess-redirect-to-language-subfolder

Comment: Yes sure, see updated answer. Now `/ru/*.jsp` OR `/de/*.jsp` goto `/en/`

Comment: hmmm my other redirects are now ignored, it's possible to add rule if nothing exist then this rules? Because there are some specific redirects like /es/about-us.jsp to /es/about-us

Comment: Yes see edited code and also you can have these rules below those rules

Comment: This was before in my htaccess file "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f", but specific url redirect still don't work, i tried this extra rules to move bofore your code and after your code, but it's not correct, can i do something like if request?

Comment: Can you post your complete .htaccess in your question for investigation.

Comment: This is a joomla htaccess file, there is firstly joomla standard data then my "Redirect /es/something.jsp" /es/someting and then your code, it think here will be long file if i post it.

Comment: Put it on pastebin and provide me a link.

Comment: Oh it says paste removed.

Comment: You need to insert my suggested line just below `## End - Custom #Redirects` line.

Comment: It's really quite a job to take an htaccess question from start to finish!... +1 :)

Comment: Thanks, Yes it is really challenging sometimes to extract correct info from OP.